# Custom window title

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating custom window title. I did it with requestWindowFeature and setFeatureInt but not work. I don't know what is wrong with this. I can't find where the errors come from.

```
public abstract class MegaActivity extends Activity {
    private final int layoutID;
    public MegaActivity(final int layoutID) {
        super();
        this.layoutID = layoutID;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(layoutID);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
    }
}

public class AsyncTaskTestActivity extends MegaActivity {

    public AsyncTaskTestActivity() {
        super(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

window_title.xml

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/megadict_icon"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/appTitle" android:textSize="16dip" android:textColor="@color/white"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

errors

```
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asynctask/com.asynctask.AsyncTaskTestActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onIntChanged(PhoneWindow.java:992)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.updateInt(PhoneWindow.java:2397)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setFeatureInt(PhoneWindow.java:933)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at com.asynctask.MegaActivity.onCreate(MegaActivity.java:20)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at com.asynctask.AsyncTaskTestActivity.onCreate(AsyncTaskTestActivity.java:26)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-06 23:42:46.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(774):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean but can't you just use the Activity.setTitle function?

Comment: I want window title has a textview and an icon, not a text string, so can't use setTitle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is AsyncTaskTestActivity  launcher activity?how did you call that activity?And the problem may be with your layouts,check your layout,whether it contains error or not?comment the  requestWindowFeature and it related information temporarily,if you still get the error the problem with resources?your answers to my questions may help you